# AWS IAM Policy to only list instances based on EC2 tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I created an IAM Role with the following Permissions policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Project": "Phoenix"
                }
            }        
        }
    ]
}
```

A 3rd party App uses the Role ARN associated with the IAM Policy to describe EC2 instances.
The objective is for the App to only be allowed describing EC2 instances tagged Project=Phoenix.
The issue is the App gets an error "*AWS credentials have insufficient permission to perform action*" so no EC2 are described at all. There are 2 instances with the matching tag.

If I remove the Condition from the policy, DescribeInstances works but the App gets all EC2 from any specified AWS Region. I need to limit the list of EC2 returned to only instances tagged Project=Phoenix.

Also tried tagging the IAM Role with Project=Phoenix as a test but same error.

Am I using & configuring the IAM Role and Policy correctly for the objective? What do I need to adjust?

EDIT: Instead of EC2 tags, I tried limiting scope based on subnet association

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:subnet/subnet-00bc6a6522a37z348"
        }
    ]
}
```

Access level=None / Resource=None / Request condition=None

*"This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition."*

Comment: I don't think it is possible to limit the results of `DecribeInstances()` based on a tag. Let us know if you find otherwise!

Comment: I can confirm, DescribeInstances does not support the condition key, you cannot control the read Actions via ec2:ResourceTag: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @f7o. How about another approach to this problem. Instead of limiting EC2 instances the App is authorized to describe based on EC2 tag, it would be an acceptable solution to base it on VPC or better yet subnet the EC2 is associated with.

Is this possible to configure in the IAM Policy JSON document?

Comment: You could try to put a deny/allow as you like for `ec2:DescribeInstances` and put the arn of the subnet inside the resource field. No time to try it right now, but let's see.

Comment: @f7o good suggestion. I tried it but no luck and edited original post to add the details.

Comment: Works for Run/TerminateInstances, i have never seen a use case actually to rescrict read actions on certain jnstances.